# why is my rendered image different from what I see in my 3D view?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, texturing, vertex-colors

I am trying to load a specific mesh with texture into blender using bpy. With a lot of help from this community, I have managed to load both the mesh and texture.

**Our question**

1) When we try to render the image, we end up with a very poor quality image. Why does this happen?

2) It is one thing if the image was just a bit blurry because of resolution issues but in this case it looks like the shape + texture is resulting in a significantly different face image which suggests that something is off with the rendering.

My best bet is that I have a bunch of "dummy vertices" at 0,0,0. My polygonal meshing algorithm includes this vertex in many cases. This can be seen in one of the attached images. Somehow this is affecting the final output?

I can post how I preprocessed data and loaded/created the mesh for interested aides.

Thank you!

[image: 3D view of mesh + texture]

[image: Rendered view of mesh + texture]

[image: Artifact of my choice of vertices and polygonal meshing]

***This is the code for rendering***

```
      #Fuck it let's start new
      import scipy.io as scio
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    sys.path.append('//home/mudigonda/blender-git/build_opencolorio/bin/')
    import bpy
    from math import radians
    import random
    import pdb

    #jubf234=scio.loadmat('/media/mudigonda/Gondor/Projects/shape-basis-3d/matlab/JUBF234.mat')
    jubf234=scio.loadmat('/media/mudigonda/Gondor/Projects/shape-basis-3d/matlab/JUHF248.mat')
    faces=jubf234['faces']
    faces = faces-1
    vertices=jubf234['vertices']
    texture=jubf234['texture']

    for object in bpy.data.objects:
        if object.name != 'Lamp' and object.name !='Camera':
            object.select = True
    objs = [l for l in bpy.data.objects]
    print(objs)

    #Deleting existing object
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    #Creating a new mesh
    mesh_3d= bpy.data.meshes.new("Human_Face")

    #converting stuff to int and making a list out of a numpy array...fuuuuuck
    #Remember that these are matlab indices, somethign to worry about
    vertex=[]
    for ii in range(vertices.shape[0]):
        vertex.append((float(vertices[ii,0]),float(vertices[ii,1]),float(vertices[ii,2])))

    #converting more stuff to int, same thing except here out of face data where face == triangles
    face=[]
    for ii in range(faces.shape[0]):
       face.append((int(faces[ii,0]),int(faces[ii,1]),int(faces[ii,2])))

    #This lets us create our own mesh of an object
    mesh_3d.from_pydata(vertex, [], face)
    #We update the scene
    mesh_3d.update()
    #creating a new object to link the object
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new("My_Object", mesh_3d)
    #we take the context
    scene = bpy.context.scene

    vertex_colors = mesh_3d.vertex_colors

    if len(vertex_colors)==0:
        vertex_colors.new()

    color_layer = vertex_colors['Col']
    i = 0
    non_zero = np.nonzero(texture)


    face_flat = faces.flatten()
    for ii in range(face_flat.shape[0]):
        color_layer.data[ii].color = list(texture[face_flat[ii],:]/255.0)

    mat = bpy.data.materials.new('vertex_material')
    mat.use_vertex_color_paint = True
    mat.use_vertex_color_light = True
    mesh_3d.materials.append(mat)


    #Experimenting with trying to set active object, seems more or less useless or a duplicate of the previous statements
    for object in bpy.data.objects:
        if object.name != 'Lamp' and object.name !='Camera':
            object.select = True
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = object

    print(bpy.context.selected_objects)
    myObj = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    print(myObj)
    #Not sure what these next pair of statements do but they are important to edit object
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    ##Resize
    myObj.scale = ((0.05,0.05,0.05))
    ##Translate
    bpy.data.objects["My_Object"].location=(0.0,0.0,0.0)

    ##camera
    ##Location
    bpy.data.objects['Camera'].location = (0.0,0.0,10.0)
    #Rotation
    bpy.data.objects['Camera'].rotation_euler = (radians(0.0),radians(0.0),radians(0.0))

    ##Move the Lamp aka Light    
    bpy.data.objects["Lamp"].location = (0.0,0.0,15.0)


    fov=150
    #FOV
    scene.camera.data.angle = fov*(np.pi/180.0)

    #Rendering file
    path = "load_face2.png"
    bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.color_mode='RGB'
    bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].render.filepath = path
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

Comment: Hmm. Apologies if things were not clear. We really tried hard to make it very clear. Could the users who put us on hold be a bit more specific with regards to questions? What we are trying to understand is -- why is the object very clear (resolution/sharpness) in the 3D view and so poorly rendered when viewed as an image?

Comment: To be even more concise -- why is Image 1 so drastically different from Image 2? (above)

Comment: What is your render resolution set to? The percentage under the image dimensions?

Comment: It is at 50%. I experimented with setting 100% and it did not help. I also experimented with multiple image sizes to render and that made no difference.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. Turns out the shader was the problem. When you iterate through the objects and turn the "shadeless = True" option ON or just change the specularity it went through fine.